# Skip watching images in compass

Tags: compass

I'm using `compass watch` and [Chrome resource mapping](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow?hl=en) to modify my .scss in the chrome browser, and it's working well.

However, everything time I save an .scss file, compass checks every sprite in its configuration, which takes about three seconds, before the .css is recompiled.

Is there a setting I can use to skip images to get more instant feedback?

Comment: You might go to config.rb which is usually in the root folder, and comment the code:

images_dir = "images"

But I don't know how your code in that file is, you might give that a try?

Comment: More info here: http://compass-style.org/help/documentation/configuration-reference/

Comment: @Leo Good thought - but it won't work, because later in my scss compass wants to know where its referenced image resources are. The idea is - the images are already compiled, but when watching, I'm not expecting changes.